# Performance comparision in registering script

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to register javascript to my page.

I want to know which one of these way has a better performance for server and why?

1. using script tag in aspx file

   ```
   <script src="/script.js"></script>
   ```
2. using codes in aspx.cs file

   ```
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude (
     typeof ( MyControl ), "includeme.js", "js/includeme.js"  );
   ```

Comment: best to use <script src="/script.js"></script> in aspx page. If you use javascript in aspx.cs page it take some time to execute the query. But if you use in client side it's faster than server side code. So best way is clientside(.aspx) code for javascript and css.